# Why is 'unexpectedly' common but 'expectedly' not?

Tags: word-choice

"unexpectedly" is common, but "expectedly" is not, whereas "predictably" (the synonym of expectedly) is common but "unpredictably" is not.  Is there any rationale for this?

See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predictably%2Cexpectedly%2C%20unexpectedly%2C%20unpredictably&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpredictably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpectedly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunexpectedly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunpredictably%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Erm... because the usual expression for the opposite of *unexpectedly* is normally ***as expected**?*.

Comment: alternative word clusters aside, I was wondering if the prefix 'un' operates differently when applied to an adverb, as opposed to an adjective.  For example, believable,believably,unbelievably,unbelievable - See GOOGLE ngrams for believable,believably,unbelievably,unbelievable at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=believable%2C+believably%2Cunbelievably%2C+unbelievable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelievable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelievably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbelievably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunbelievable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: See also inexplicably,explicably,inexplicable,explicable as a GOOGLE NGRAM at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inexplicably%2C+explicably%2C+inexplicable%2C+explicable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinexplicably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplicably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinexplicable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplicable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's probably relevant to note that strictly speaking the extremely rare verb **to unbelieve** doesn't actually mean *to reverse one's previous state of "belief"*, whereas that *is* the underlying type of negation in the not-quite-so-rare **unthink**. Negation comes in many forms, and words having to do with presuppositions and attempts to alter the opinions of others are *particularly* "slippery".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a rationale for why any word is common or uncommon?  Common, in this context, simply means it is used more often.  But certainly there are more drastic instances of where "un" or "dis" words appear with little to no use of the un-prefixed version.  Example: disheveled but no sheveled.  Unkempt but not kempt.  Inscrutable but no scrutable.

"Lonely negatives" some call them [[http://wordsnooper.com/2011/02/24/scrutable-inscrutable/]](http://wordsnooper.com/2011/02/24/scrutable-inscrutable/%5d)

Comment: _Disheveled_ is a particularly striking case because if you took the negating "dis-" away you'd be left with _heveled_; but the Middle English word from which _disheveled_ arose is _discheveled_ (meaning "bareheaded, with disordered hair," according to Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary). That dictionary identifies one surviving form of the Anglo-French root word _chevoil_ in modern English: _chevelure_ ("a head of hair"). I've never seen or heard that term used.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said that "expectedly" is just a neologism. But what is the problem, grammatically? We notice that both words involve time and tense structure: to expect is to focus on the future from some determined point in time. To predict is to designate a future point in time, when something will happen.
"He faced an expectedly tough challenge". Adverbs contain adjectives. If you do something advisedly, you were advised. But here when you compartmentalize the past tense itself into an adverb, you are using a word that sort of tilts to the future in order to describe a state of mind or affairs in the past. It is bad style, if nothing else. (Whether or not it was some sort of creative back formation from "unexpectedly", I do not know.)
So, I don't like expectedly at all. If "predictably" doesn't suit, then there are other ways. The important thing is always to properly schematize the time relationships between items.
"Inscrutable" comes to be because certain things yield little to scrutiny. Numerical use analysis of medieval texts ought to show something. "Scrutiny" means not just to look at something but to scratch it (to score). It means looking very closely. And certain principles of nature refuse to reveal themselves. The hidden mainsprings, above all of Nature's work, elude our explanation. 
"The oracle at Delphi does not speak, does not dissemble; he signifies." That which is otherwise inscrutable is taken to mean something, but the meaning has to be accepted, because no analysis is possible. As Kant said, much about freedom can be explained, except how it is possible.
So, it's not just how this word got separated from this other cognate pair. It's a matter of the meaning of inscrutable. First, there had to be something inscrutable, and in various ways the gods fulfilled this. There wishes and words are significant - but they don't yield any rules of analysis. They can't be gamed out.
In the end, inscrutability has something to do with the invisibility of God himself. That which is inscrutable defies investigation and yet offers something to be thought.

And so by contrast that which is "scrutable" simply partakes of the ordinary. It would love to be scrutinized, but predictably, we expect nothing from it

Comment: Google [N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expectedly&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cexpectedly%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bexpectedly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BExpectedly%3B%2Cc0) viewer indicates it's use before 1800, so probably not a neologism.