# English subways have 'Cars', but English Surface Trains have 'Carriages'. Why the Difference?

Tags: british-english

I heard both terms used in an episode of 'Sherlock'. It seems like one term or the other should do for both surface and underground trains.

Comment: Carriage: Chiefly British,  A railroad passenger car.
Cars is the term that can be used in both cases.

Comment: Carriage is also used for underground trains. For [example](http://metro.co.uk/2013/08/29/terrified-passengers-flee-smoke-filled-tube-carriage-on-the-central-line-3942056/): *Terrified passengers flee smoke filled Tube carriage on the Central line*

Comment: If by 'English' you are referring to the United Kingdom, as opposed to the English language, then it is true that our *Underground* (Subways have no trains, they are pedestrian underpasses) trains have *cars*, whilst surface trains have 'carriages*. I have no idea of the reason for the difference, but it doesn't cause me anguish. I assume, in any event that *car* is an abbreviation for *carriage*?

Comment: @Hugo My impression is that the term *car* tends to be used by staff on the London Underground, when making announcements etc. But much of the public probably uses *carriage*.

Comment: @WS2 Actually, though they're related etymologically, there's no direct relation between _car_ and _carriage_. The former is straight from Latin (a Celtic loan word), while the latter is from the verb _carry_ (which is ultimately from the same Latin noun, the original sense being carrying by car).

Comment: If we use the same word for different things, [people complain](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176958/why-doesnt-english-have-a-separate-word-for-head-hair-head-hair-vs-body-ha). If we use different words for different things, [people complain](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/english-subways-have-cars-but-english-surface-trains-have-carriages-why-th).

Comment: Within railway terminology, *carriage* is generic. *Car* is mostly used with reference to specific type such as 'dining car,' 'chair car,' 'pantry car,' and so on. The London Underground has specially designed 'cars' different from the run-of-the-mill carriages of the legacy trains. *Metro Rail* in other countries today has 'cars' as well, not 'carriages' or 'coaches.'

Comment: I'm surprised by some of the comments. I've used the London Underground and I haven't heard the word *car* used in that context. I've only heard the word *carriage*.

Comment: user3847, the use of both terms may have been for the benefit of American viewers. The word *car* is not, normally used in that context in the UK. Neither is the word is the word *subway*, which is why this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/subway_2 says mainly **US**. Normally, people use the word *carriage* for both **overground** (not *surface*) and underground trains.

Comment: user3847, my preference (ie, a criterion I expect to see met before I upvote a question) is that the body of a posted question states the question in its entirety, rather than fracturing the question into pieces and putting part of it in the post's title and part in the body.  Having an accurate and descriptive title (as you do) is good, but that cannot substitute for a complete statement of the question in the body of the post.

Comment: English [subways](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/subway) are not the same as American subways!! EDIT: Oops, Tristan said the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think this was explained in the episode of *Sherlock*. The terminology depends on who supplied the original carriages or coaches. In the case of the London Underground, it was the American company (American Car and Foundry), and the American term stuck with people employed in the London Underground. That is also why British trains have 'buffet cars'. Members of the public, however, are likely to use terminology from the railways and talk about carriages or coaches.

Comment: It is not just the supplier of the coaches/cars.  The early London Underground was designed by American engineers.  To this day the signalling principles are different from the overground and the terminology uses american nomenclature, e.g. Points are called Switches.  There are many gricing sites on the web that give a lot more detail for this.

Comment: People who work on the London Underground may refer to them as _cars_, but I would never call them anything but _carriages_.

Comment: Colin, I agree. Having used the London Underground, I haven't heard the word *car* used in that context. Only the word *carriage*.

Comment: Blame Charles Tyson Yerkes for the 'car' thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was on my way home on Saturday afternoon when an announcer of the recorded message on the Piccadilly line clearly asked passangers to 'move down inside the cars please'.
Car as a term is clearly still in use on the tube....