# Specific word for the hairs on head

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there words that describe the head-hairs, just being curious.

Comment: Related question: [Why doesn't English have a separate word for “head hair”? (head hair vs. body hair)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176958/why-doesnt-english-have-a-separate-word-for-head-hair-head-hair-vs-body-ha) Hope it will help.

Comment: "Scalp hair" is the term I'd use, if not writing poetry.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know of a specific word to describe one hair, may I suggest:

**Locks:** somebody's locks being their head hair, never confused with their body hair. However, one "Lock" of hair is not a single strand, it is generally a small bunch of head hair from one place on the head. (think: **lock**et, used to store a single lock of a loved one's hair.)